# How to change the text of details tab on product page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-page

Can any one tell me how to change the text of detail tab in  product page.

check the site url :http://apetrailportfolio.com/mod/demo9.html

Comment: which theme you are using

Answer (score 10):

**`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_layout.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">About</argument> //set your custom tab name
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Customer Reviews</argument> //set your custom tab name
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hey, It's working fine. how to find the name "reviews.tab" i can't find in the "vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml ".

Answer (score 9):

Open your custom theme `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And add below code in the end of you `XML` file before **body tag**

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <action method="setTitle">
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Your text here</argument>
                </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Keep cache disabled or clear your cache

Comment: It's a working solution and pure magento way of changing tab name